# Прошу подсказать регулярное выражение, чтобы заменить 044, 029 на +37544, +37529

Tags: php

Есть регулярка, которая убирает побелы, дефисы, скобки, и некоторые числа, но не хватает для полной картины регулярных выражений 044, 029 на +37544, +37529

```
  $pattern = [
        '~(?:[^\d\s]+|(?<=\d)\s(?=\d))~',
        '~(?<=\b)(?=\d)~',
        '~\b80(\d+\b)~'
    ];
```

Comment: а как Ваши регулярки потом используются? а для замены достаточно чего то вида `s/^0(44|29)/+375(\1)/`

Comment: перезаписываю номера телефон в базе клиентов, привожу их в единый формат, а то не ставил ограничения при вводе, теперь поназаписывали кто как умеет

Comment: $pattern = [
        '~(?:[^\d\s]+|(?<=\d)\s(?=\d))~',
        '~(?<=\b)(?=\d)~',
        '~\b80(\d+\b)~'
    ];
    $replace = ['', '+', '37$1'];
    $masiv[$user_id] = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/0(44|29)/", "+375$1", $string);
```